# how to implement State Override for eth_call usinggithub.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient package

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I'm so confused, because the lack of State Override variable on CallContract method on `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient` package, the only variable that available is `ctx context.Context, msg ethereum.CallMsg, blockNumber *big.Int`.
I have searched the source code manually, still can't find State Override variable
Is my only option is to call the eth_call rpc manually using http package ?

reference https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-eth